# Run Special Tasks According To User Defined Times

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I'm surprised I haven't been able to find something on this here - so if I've just completely missed it, please direct me to the proper thread.

Before I dive into any code, I'm trying to gather some good ideas for handling this situation.

We're developing a website with a list of tasks the user can select for the server to execute on their behalf. Automated emails, text messages, calendar reminders, etc.

I first went down the road of thinking about using cron, but as that the times and tasks for each user will likely change every day throughout each day - for this to be feasibly salable, I figured involving cron directly for each task could get pretty messy and buggy.

My next thought was to run a cron script every night at midnight and generate a task-list for the next day - but I'd still need cron or some sort of cron-like timing daemon to check the list against the time every minute.

I've run through several ideas, but they all seem fairly active or processor heavy. I'd like to find a good light-weight solution that can handle up to several thousand user defined tasks per day.

I'm working with your basic LAMP7 stack. If anybody has dealt with a similar task, I'm just looking for some good ideas to consider.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look at Message Queuing, such as RabbitMQ: https://www.rabbitmq.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org) application run in background in your machine.

Then you can create a simple [http server](https://reactphp.org/http/) on your ReactPHP application for recieving the user data from your webserver such as you specified LAMP7. And once you recieved that you can trigger those events by setting asyncronous timer on the [event-loop](https://reactphp.org/event-loop/).

Comment: great - thanks. I'll give both suggestions a shot and see how they work out :)

Comment: And plus if you are new to async/non-blocking-IO then i'll suggest you exploring more about event-loops https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJFbYHYxSDg&list=PLKIEFFgNQYpVmUAKUjT_BRYYOdMHwGt0v